# How to insert values a json array at a specific index in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular10

I have a JSON array as below,

```
this.sampleArray = [
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      },
      {
        "start_time": "",
        "end_time": ""
      }
    ];
```

I want to insert data to this array based on a value at a specific index. I am not sure how to proceed further. Any suggestions on how to proceed further would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean you are not sure how to proceed, what have you tried except for typing your array here? Did you look at `splice`?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily replace with array splice method. Following code will replace existing item with new item.

```
sampleArray.splice(4, 1, {start_time: new Date(), end_time: new Date() });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the deconstructing assignment

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var insertValue = 8;
var insertAt = 1;

[...arr[insertAt]] = [insertValue, arr[insertAt]];

arr = arr.flat();

console.log(arr);
```